# onClick not firing click handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My click handler doesn't fire:

```
submitForm(UserDetails) {
    axios
        .post('http://localhost:3001/api/users', UserDetails)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

ON my button:

```
<button
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={this.submitForm(this.props.UserDetails)}>
            Upload
        </button>
```

I have bound it to this, in my constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is there any error, in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onClick hook you're invoking the function instead of passing a reference of the function

```
<button
  className="btn btn-primary"
  onClick={this.submitForm(this.props.UserDetails)}>
  Upload
</button>
```

remove the bind from the constructor

```
this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
```

and pass a proper function to the onClick

```
<button
  className="btn btn-primary"
  onClick={(e) => this.submitForm(this.props.UserDetails)}>
  Upload
</button>
```